# CSS rules to switch content if it does not fit

Tags: css

Having a menu like this (emphasized by a red rectangle)...

[image]

how can I (in pure CSS) make this responsive so that, if there is not enough width available, the menu turns into a drop-down list (or anyway something smaller).

The question is not about implementing the drop-down list itself, but how to switch from one content to the other depending on available space.

I know this is rather simple when using `@media max-width` queries, but the problem is that I do not know the actual with of the menu items at "design time" - especially because the text gets translated and/or changed, leading to different widths depending on the actual language displayed.

Perhaps, there is some CSS trick that makes a whole "text" line / content disappear if it does not fit the parent container?

Comment: I don't know a solution in pure CSS, but think that your task is possible if you will check a menu item height (in case of a long label, you will have several rows of text, so the height will be greater)

Comment: @fremail you mean using JavaScript?

Comment: I saw this one is quite good, is this what you mean ? 
http://purecss.io/layouts/tucked-menu-vertical/#

Comment: @trungk18 yeah that seems to be the solution I was looking for. However, I don't really understand how this works, especially why `@media (max-width: 47.999em)` has been choosen to hide the menu (where does that value come from?) and what makes the `class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-3"` <DIV> move downward (and thus overflow) when there is not enough space. I guess this is about word wrapping, but some clarification would help a lot.

Comment: The width of the element is calculated after the rendering, based on it's content (and other css values) so I really don't think you can apply a css value based on some other value (without using javascript). Is there a specific reason you want  a pure css solution here? The js code shouldn't be complex...

Comment: @trungk18 - your link is doesn't give a solution based on the content, but it's based on a grid-system (`@media screen and (min-width: 48em)
.pure-u-md-1-3, .pure-u-md-8-24 { width: 33.3333%; }` )

Comment: @Dekel: Thanks for pointing out, it is based on grid-system. To implement this based on the content is actually more complicated and It might not be done by only CSS.

Comment: @UdoG yes, I mean using JavaScript

Comment: @UdoG: If you want to understand the magic of responsive navigation, please check http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav.asp

Comment: i don't know of a pure CSS solution when dealing with unknown widths or number of items. I've attempted in the past, but ended up resorting to jQuery. http://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/Responsive-Overflow-Off-canvas-Navigation-Plugin-With-jQuery-okayNav.html and http://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/Responsive-Horizontal-Nav-Menu-with-jQuery-CSS.html have both worked well for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution I've just come up with that should do the job. I added some style to make the structure more evident but it's not pixel perfect, you'll have to take care of that. Run the snippet in full screen and resize the window to see it in action.

```css
.table-row{
    display: table-row;
}
.table-cell{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.wrapper{
   height:75px; /*the height of your menu, it's critical to define this value equal to the horizontal menu height*/
   overflow:hidden; /*this will hide the horizontal menu when the screen width is too small*/
}

.top_nav{
   padding-right:120px; /*allow space for right section*/
   background-color: green;
   color:white;
}
.top_nav_background{ /* this serves as a background for the rest of the structure, pay attention if you have other z-indexed elements */
   background-color:green; 
   height:85px; 
   width:100%; 
   position:absolute; 
   top:0px; 
   z-index:-1;
}
.floating-box {
    height: 55px;
    padding:10px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #73AD21;
    background-color:green;
}
.h-menu{
    height: 75px;
    float: left;
    min-width: 150px;
    background-color:yellow;
}
.h-menu-item{
   height: 55px;
   padding:10px;
   border: 1px solid #73AD21;
}
.v-menu{
    margin-top:20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color:red;
}
.right-items{
   position:absolute; 
   right:20px; 
   top:20px; 
   color:white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div class="top_nav_background"></div>
<div class="top_nav table-cell">
  
   <div class="wrapper">

     <div class="floating-box">Left section.</div>

     <div class="h-menu table-row">
        <div class="table-cell h-menu-item"><a href="yourpage.htm">item1</a></div>
        <div class="table-cell h-menu-item"><a href="yourpage.htm">item2</a></div>
        <div class="table-cell h-menu-item"><a href="yourpage.htm">item3</a></div>
        <div class="table-cell h-menu-item"><a href="yourpage.htm">long long long item4</a></div>
     </div>
     <div class="v-menu">v-menu</div>
     
   </div>
   
   <div class="table-cell right-items">Right section.</div>
</div>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the `float: top;` is not a CSS property ;)

Answer (score 1):

In one project I did I came up with a solution where you show part or all of the menu and only show it as a dropdown/side-menu when the screen gets smaller.

The sub-menu is optional and you can just use the main menu for your effect.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LRJoEB

```
<nav id="top-menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="link menu" tabindex="0">
      Menu
    </li>
    <li class="link">
      <a class="help" href="#">Help</a>
    </li>
    <li class="link">
      <a class="account" href="#">My Account</a>
    </li>
    <li class="sub-nav">
      <nav id="sub-menu">
        <ul>
          <li class="sub-link">
            <a class="details" href="#">My Details</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div id="close-menu" tabindex="0"></div>
      </nav>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Just change the bits and parts to fit your needs, should you get stuck just leave a comment ;)

#### edit

Just realised you don't want to be using any media queries. I'll see if I can come up with something in that direction, not off the top of my head.